# How to use a library project built with dagger 2 in another project?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-library

I have two projects, say 'project A' and 'project B'. Both using dagger 2 dependency injection. Project B require many files from A. Is it possible to use A as a library in B ?